# Are players who go AFK automatically penalised?

Tags: league-of-legends

In League of Legends, there are a lot of people who rage and cry about their teammates. This usually results in 1 of 2 things. Either they rage-quit the match, or they go "afk" at base. I'm aware of the 5 minute leave timer, where a player who's inactive for 5 minutes gets kicked and marked as a leaver if they don't return.

What about people who say they'll afk at base, but make sure they don't get autokicked by staying in to chat or by moving their mouse? Is there some kind of check for that, and are they penalised (besides being reported for being afk)?

Comment: you mean if there was any way to determine if a player were "afk", so moving inside the base and doing nothing else, or a player going baseafk at the end of the game and not doing nothing for the last few minutes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any bonus for playing 4 v 5 games?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/116427/are-there-any-bonus-for-playing-4-v-5-games)

Comment: @Vogel612 I actually meant both.

Comment: @Ender please re-consider your duplicate report.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do Leavers gain rewards?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61373/do-leavers-gain-rewards)

Comment: @Marco its not for me to reconsider, its for the community to decide, i'm not sure it's a duplicate, but it might be, hence **POSSIBLE** *duplicate*

Comment: I edited the question to reflect what I think it's asking. Marco, please revert if I got it wrong.

Comment: @Michel certainly not a duplicate of that question, as the subject is a totally different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Players whose name is displayed in red in the post-game score screen have already been flagged as AFK (which means they have been automatically disconnected, most of the time).

You can also report a player for being AFK if the server failed to notice. Players who run in circles at their fountain to bypass AFK detection can be flagged this way.

Players who have been flagged as AFK, be it automatically or manually, are then handled by LeaveBuster (NOT the Tribunal). See [How exactly does Leave Buster work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/114156/how-exactly-does-leave-buster-work).

There is no way to make sure they will be punished. You have to trust LeaveBuster for that.

Answer (score 3):

If they are really AFK, they will get disconnected. But if they stay in game, and just stays in spawn and walk arount, there is nothing much to do, expect reporting them.

Comment: Sadly this is right. Hopefully Riot will eventually be able to do something about it though.

Comment: Isn't that enough? Human judgement through reports can be as efficient, if not more, than any other kind of detection system.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't see how many matches a player left before the match was finished. However if that player receives a lot of leaving reports he will get reviewed by a council of players and community members. First they might issue a warning, then a temporary ban but continually disrupting gameplay like leaving will eventually result in a permanent ban. Not sure if this is an IP ban since the player can just make a new account with another free email address. So keep reporting people who leave, smash talk, intentional feeders, etc.

However the further you rank up the better and more serious the players will be. There is already a significant different between being level 10 and lvl 20.